# Running a Maven project as an application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have imported a whole project into Eclipse using `Import , Maven , Existing Maven Projects` menu options.

For running it, I'm presented with some options: Run as a:

- Java Application
- Java server
- Applet
- Maven Clean
- Maven Install
- etc.

Should I just run it as a Java application, like what I always do with my Java programs in Eclipse? (Eclipse Juno on Mac 10.7.5)

Thank you.

Comment: You should study maven. `Maven Install` builds your artifact for example. If you are building a wep app, you would build it and deploy to your server. If you are building a desktop app I guess you could launch it from Eclipse using "Run as Java Application".

Comment: its not that simple with maven. what kind of project is it? java, Web app?